# Why can I bind a T& to rvalue in VS2015?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm using VS2015, and I have tested in both debug and release mode, they have the same result.

```
int &a=1;//it's wrong, can't compile, it is what I predict to happen.
std::string &s=std::string("abc");//success to compile, looks weird to me.
```

As I know, you can only bind a rvalue with T&& or const T&,but not with T&.
Can any one tell me why does the second line of the code can pass the compiler's check?

Comment: It should not. I bet it's a bug of VS.

Comment: visual extension.... You can disable it with`/Za` (and not have `/Ze`).

Comment: @songyuanyao It's a feature ;)

Comment: @NathanOliver A feature against the standard...Okay, I would continue to call it bug. :)